# Is the use of Module#module_function considered bad?

Tags: ruby, module

Seems like if you're looking to be able to call methods on a Module(/Class), you're looking for a singleton... And if that's the case, you're better of using class methods or the `Singleton` mixin (not looking for answers on which one of those is "better").

The only benefit (?) I can see in using `#module_function` is the flexibility to mix in the module as well as call methods on the module.  Is there anything else?

I ran across some old code that used to work < 1.9.3, but doesn't anymore and am looking to fix.  It looked something like this:

```
module MyThing
  def self.do_something
    ...
  end
end
```

...and allowed for:

```
MyThing.do_something
```

I'm not trying to argue that this design was a good one--just trying to figure out what the best way is to fix it.  Leaning towards a standard Module...

**Update...**

I'd incorrectly simplified my problem and example.  The differing behavior that I'm experiencing is during my RSpec tests--they pass using RSpec 2.8.0 with MRI 1.9.2, but fail with MRI 1.9.3.  The module looks like:

```
module MyThing
  module SubThing
    module SubSubThing
      def self.do_something
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

...and tests:

```
describe MyThing::SubThing::SubSubThing do
  include MyThing::SubThing

  describe "#do_something" do
    it "does something" do
      SubSubThing.do_something
    end
  end
end
```

When running the specs under 1.9.3, I get `NameError: uninitialized constant DataGathering`; under 1.9.2, they pass.  That led me to incorrectly diagnose the problem and present what I did above.  Seems as if `include` behavior is different in 1.9.3.  That's fine; my question still stands: does `#module_function` provide something special?

Comment: Your example works here - running Ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [x86_64-darwin11.0.0].

Comment: Thanks for checking; that made me realize I'd incorrectly diagnosed the problem.  I've updated to describe the real issue.

Comment: FWIW, looks like my 1.9.2 v. 1.9.3 problem was logged as [a 1.9.3 bug](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5657) (originally [logged by Matz](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4536)), but turned out to be a 1.9.2 bug.  Go figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `module_function` is exactly that which you mentioned in your question: it gives you the flexibility to explicitly call class methods on a module, using the module name, or to mix it in and make things a bit more concise.

You can also do the same thing with `extend self` (inside the module definition). The difference is that if you mix in a module which uses `module_function`, the mixed-in methods will become *private* instance methods (but they will be public class methods of the declaring module); if you use `extend self`, they will have whatever access qualifier was used in the module definition, *both* when mixed-in and when called directly on the module as class methods.

Comment: I just did some quick tests in `irb`, and corrected my answer.

Comment: Looking back at this post, I might add that I consider the `Singleton` mixin (since the OP mentioned it) almost useless. If you want a "singleton", just create a new object (using `Object.new`), and define whatever methods you need on it.

Answer (score 0):

Module in Ruby is abstractly equivalent to Namespace in C++. This should be fine for Ruby 1.9.3:

```
module MyThing
   def MyThing.do_something
      # ...
   end
end
```

do_something could also be implemented as an instance method of MyThing, which is where things get murky.

Comment: You're right; I incorrectly described my problem.  Updated accordingly.